# How to move two sprite object in one screen in android libgdx?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I want to **add motion to two sprite objects in single game screen**. I mean two sprite object should move(or follow some predefined path) independently in single page or game screen of app using **Libgdx**. How can I achieve that.
Please help me. If possible please provide some reference code also. Thank you.

Comment: You should just change their coordinates from render method. Did you try something already? What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

you can use scene2d for this purpose.where you can easily move object through actions.
you can follow these links to learn scene2d.

http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2013/11/27/LibGDX-Tutorial-9-Scene2D-Part-1.aspx

http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2013/12/09/LibGDX-Tutorial-9-Scene2D-Part-2-Actions.aspx

i hope these links will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

take two 2DVector objects:

```
private Vector2 positiononesprite,positiontwosprite;
Sprite sprite_one,sprite_two;
```

then in your create method do this

```
positiononesprite = new Vector2(0,0);
positiontwosprite = new Vector2(0,0);

//set your sprite position
sprite_one.setPosition(x,y);//your x and y coordinates
sprite_two.setPosition(x1,y1);//your second sprite postions

positiononesprite.x = sprite_one.getX();
positiononesprite.y = sprite_one.getY();

positiontwosprite.x = sprite_two.getX();
positiontwosprite.y = sprite_two.getY();

/*
then to make them move in a custom direction you can use either
setPosition method or translate method*/

//apply your algorithm on vectors and set or translate your sprites
//    in render method define there speed, direction and move them
//for example i did this to move it in a particular direction

pointerposition.x += directionpointer.x * speed;
            pointerposition.y += directionpointer.y * speed;

            // pointer.setPosition(pointerposition.x, pointerposition.y);
            ball.setPosition(pointerposition.x, pointerposition.y);
```

this is moving my ball in a particular direction
here directionpointer is a direction vector and speed is a float variable and pointerposition is a vector2 object as i declared positiononesprite